# What is the meaning of the daemon facility in rsyslog.conf on Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I'm looking for detailed information about what the daemon facility would log if configured in /etc/rsyslog.conf.

So far, the most detail I have found is:
daemon: affects a daemon without any special classification (DNS, NTP, etc.) (https://debian-handbook.info/browse/squeeze/sect.syslog.html)

Does anyone have a more detailed explanation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsyslog is more advanced version of the grand old syslog. The facility code denotes which system is logging the message.

Facility codes are specified in [RFC 5424](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424):

```
          Numerical             Facility
             Code

              0             kernel messages
              1             user-level messages
              2             mail system
              3             system daemons
              4             security/authorization messages
              5             messages generated internally by syslogd
              6             line printer subsystem
              7             network news subsystem
              8             UUCP subsystem
              9             clock daemon
             10             security/authorization messages
             11             FTP daemon
             12             NTP subsystem
             13             log audit
             14             log alert
             15             clock daemon (note 2)
             16             local use 0  (local0)
             17             local use 1  (local1)
             18             local use 2  (local2)
             19             local use 3  (local3)
             20             local use 4  (local4)
             21             local use 5  (local5)
             22             local use 6  (local6)
             23             local use 7  (local7)
```

Not all facilities are available in all implementations.

`daemon` is a catch-all, it facilitates logging for otherwise unspecified sources. For example it would be used to facilitate handling syslog messages from an application you wrote yourself.

- Wikipedia [Syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog)
- O'Reilly [Practical UNIX & Internet Security](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking/puis/ch10_05.htm#PUIS-CHP-10-TAB-1)
- rsyslog [homepage](https://www.rsyslog.com)

Comment: You're very welcome :-) These sites aren't discussion board, the way to say "thanks" in SE sites is a bit different. You should [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) a helpful answer. It's a good idea to take the[Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how these sites work.